# ToolbarButton - Insufficient width for caption

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I want to add a caption to a toolbar button (with an icon) because if the button is grayed out (disabled) the description is not displayed.
Caption is also displayed if the button is not enabled...

My problem is that I can't figure out how to enlarge the ToolbarButton field to fit the caption.
The caption consists of 3 words and currently only the first word is displayed due to lack of space - relevant code snippet:

```
     toolbarButton = new ToolbarButton();
     toolbarButton.setIcon(ImgRes.ICON_PREVIEW);
     toolbarButton.setDescription("Preview Button Description");
     toolbarButton.setCaption("Preview Button Caption");
     toolbarButton.setWidth("100%");
     toolbarButton.setEnabled(false);       
     toolbarButton.addClickListener(e -> onPreviewButtonClicked());

     return toolbarButton;
 }
```

Can anyone help me how to solve my problem?

Comment: Using methods like `setCaption` and `setDescription` makes me believe you are using Vaadin 6/7/8, and not Vaadin Flow (10+).

Comment: I am migrating currently to Flow.

Anyways, would you know a possibility to solve my problem using Flow?

Comment: Is ToolbarButton some add-on or something custom in your applicaton? As far as I recall there is no such component in V6/7/8 either.

Comment: In this case, I guess it might be a custom add-on which inherits from  NativeButton.
Maybe my problem would be solved if I would know how to solve the exact same problem for a NativeButton?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the min-width of the button so that it will always fit the content inside it:

```java
toolbarButton.setMinWidth("max-content");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, this has worked out for me :)
I need apparently more reputation to upvote your helpful reply, but in my heart I upvote it heavily :) Thanks again^^

Comment: Thanks, glad to help! No worries about the upvotes :)